# subprocess in python cannot create & activate conda venv

Tags: python, subprocess, conda

Currently I am tryting to, in a python script,

1. create a conda venv in a temp dir with a different python version I am using in my system
2. install some packages into this temp conda venv
3. Execute other python script using this new venv
4. Kill the process (which is automatic since it is under with .... as ..:)

```
import subprocess
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:

    subprocess.call([
        f"""
        conda create -p {tmpdir}/temp_venv python=3.8 <<< y; 
        conda activate {tmpdir}/temp_venv && pip install <some_package>==XXX; 
        {tmpdir}/temp_venv/bin/python /path/to/python/script/test.py
        """
    ],
shell=True)
```

The point is that when I try this approach, I get the following error

**CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.**

I have already tried running conda init bash but the error persists.

I have also tried to use the Venv package for that but unfortunately it does not let me create a venv with a python version that is not installed in the system.

Comment: "which is automatic since it is under with .... as ..:" mmm the process won't be killed automatically by your `TemporaryDirectory` context manager, but `subprocess.call` should block until the command termiantes (note, you should use `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.call` is from an oudated API left around for backwards compatibility)

Comment: Just so you're clear, your `with` statement has nothing to do with the process.  It will destroy the tmpdir object for you but that's it.  And nothing here "kills" the process.  `subprocess.call` will block until the process completes.

Comment: Remember that `conda init` has to be run as part of that shell.  You can't run it beforehand.

Comment: @TimRoberts it doesn't. `conda init` essentialyl adds something to your shell's login scripts (`~/.bash_profile` , `~/.bashrc` depending on OS etc). The problem is that `subprocess` isn't running an interactive shell, so none of those scripts are run beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is that `conda` expects your shell to be initialized normally (an interactive shell). But when you use `subprocess`, you are in a non-login, non-interactive shell. So, one hack would be to manually call the shell startup script. So for example, on my Macbook Pro:

```
subprocess.run([
    f"""
    conda create -y -p {tmpdir}/temp_venv python=3.8;
    conda init 
    source ~/.bash_profile
    conda activate {tmpdir}/temp_venv && pip install <some_package>==XXX; 
    {tmpdir}/temp_venv/bin/python /path/to/python/script/test.py
    """
],
shell=True)
```

Of course, this is going to be a bit platform dependent. For example, on Ubuntu, you are going to want to use:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

instead.

A more portable solution would be to get `subprocess.run` to use an interactive shell, that would automatically call those scripts according to the convention of your OS (which `conda` handles setting up correctly).

So, this is definitely a hack, but it should work.

BTW, if you are using `conda`, you might as well use:

```
conda create -y -p {tmpdir}/temp_venv python=3.8 <some_package>==XXX
```

instead of a seperate:

```
pip install <some_package>==XXX;
```

A less hacky alternative is to use `conda run`, which will run a script in the conda environment. So something like:

```
subprocess.run([
    f"""
    conda create -y -p {tmpdir}/temp_venv python=3.8;
    conda run -p {tmpdir}/temp_venv --no-capture-output  pip install <some_package>==XXX; 
    conda run -p {tmpdir}/temp_venv/bin/python --no-capture-output /path/to/python/script/test.py
    """
],
shell=True)
```

I hesitate to use `conda run` because, [at least a few years ago, it was considered "broken"](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9599) for various subtle reasons, although, in simple cases it works. I think it is still considered an "experimental feature", so use with that caveat in mind, but it should be more portable.